# How can I use Jasmine in Cloud9?

Tags: jasmine, cloud9-ide

I use Jasmine (BDD for JavaScript) regularly and just discovered Cloud9 and want to give it a try.

On my local machine, I use jasmine-node to run my specs, but I have no idea, how to do this within Cloud9.
I was able to use the console bar at the bottom of the Cloud9 editor to somehow install jasmine-node via npm, but I was not able to use it.

I write the code in CoffeeScript, but this should not be the problem, I tried JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a run-tests.js file to the project which contains an adaption of the jasmine-node script. In this example, production code is under a lib folder parallel to the run-tests.js file.

Run config:

```
File path:              run-tests.js
Command line arguments: --coffee spec
```

run-tests.js

```
if( !process.env.NODE_ENV ) process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var path = require('path');

// find out the current paths
//console.log(require.paths);
// I have ~/.node_modules in there, which did not exist and did a
// ln -s ~/local/lib/node_modules/ ~/.node_modules
// my jasmine-node/cli.js is in
// ~/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js

// Add the local lib path to allow the specs to require from there
require.paths.unshift(path.join(__dirname, 'lib'));

require('jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js');
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of this 'run-tests.js'  script? When I try this I get an error about require.paths being removed. Could you update this answer and give a sort of walkthrough of how to actually run tests using this script? I missing some vital pieces of the puzzle. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Cloud9 you are able to do:

```
npm install -g jasmine-node
```

Then use the simplified script as `run-tests.js`:

```
require('jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js');
```

That's all (at least it was for me). Just don't forget to name your spec files as `.spec.js`